# Drop down div infront of or blocking its dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, menu, dropdown

I am having this problem where my dropdown menu content comes in front of its menu. I have tried everything and searched stackoverflow but i cant seem to find the answer. Please take a look at it for me. Thanks

### Here is the Code

```css
#box {
  width: 180px;
  min-height: 570px;
  background: #4D4D4D;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 9999;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*shadows  */
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 3px #333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 3px #333;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 3px #333;
  -o-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 3px #333;
  /* transparency  */
  opacity: 0.9;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

#box-under {
  width: 600px;
  min-height: 583px;
  background: #4D4D4D;
  position: absolute;
  right: -600px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*shadows  */
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 3px #333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 3px #333;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 3px #333;
  -o-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 3px #333;
  /* transparency  */
  opacity: 0.9;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  /* For IE8 and earlier */
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 1.13) 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 1.13) 0s;
}


/*  xxxxxxxx testing drop down  xxxxxxxx  */

#keys:hover #box-under {
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#box:hover #box-under {
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.butz:hover #box-under #box {
  z-index: 999;
  right: 0px;
}


/*  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  */

#logoz {
  min-height: 40px;
  background: #555555;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1.4em;
}

.butz {
  min-height: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #304565;
  padding: 0.9em;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #CCC;
}

.butz:hover {
  background: #218F77;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.butz2 {
  min-height: 20px;
  background: #555555;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #CCC;
  display: flex;
}

.butz2-in:hover {
  background: #41967C;
  color: #FFF;
  border-bottom: #41967C 4px solid;
}

.butz2-in {
  min-height: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #555555;
  padding: 0.9em;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #CCC;
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: #777 4px solid;
}

.butz2-out {
  min-height: 20px;
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #777;
  padding: 0.55em 0.9em;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #CCC;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-bottom: #00B2B2 4px solid;
}

.butz3 {
  min-height: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #dddddd;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1.3em 0.9em;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
}

.butz3:hover {
  background: #CCC;
  color: #2E2E2E;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="logoz">
    <img src="images/page_logo.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <!--  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  -->
  <!--  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  -->
  <div class="butz" id="keys">KEY FEATURES<br />
    <small>The summaries is gone</small>
    <!--  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  -->
    <div id="box-under"></div>
    <!--  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  -->
  </div>
  <!--  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  -->
  <!--  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  -->
  <!--  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  -->
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <div class="butz2">
    <div class="butz2-in">The Company</div>
    <div class="butz2-out"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i></div>
  </div>
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <!--  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  -->
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <div class="butz2">
    <div class="butz2-in">Our Services</div>
    <div class="butz2-out"><i class="fas fa-angle-doub`enter code here`le-left"></i></div>
  </div>
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <div class="butz2">
    <div class="butz2-in">Our Works</div>
    <div class="butz2-out"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i></div>
  </div>
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <div class="butz2">
    <div class="butz2-in">Contact Info</div>
    <div class="butz2-out"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i></div>
  </div>
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <div class="butz3">
    <span class="cube"><i class="fas fa-align-left"></i></span>
    <span class="notes">To maintain and expand our oursd and to...</span>
  </div>
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <div class="butz3">
    <span class="cube"><i class="far fa-bookmark"></i></span> To maintain our commercial presence...
  </div>
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <div class="butz3">
    <span class="cube"><i class="fab fa-odnoklassniki"></i></span> To maintain and expand our commercial to...
  </div>
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <!--  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  -->
</div>
```

---

This is what it looks like.

[static state[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHvFC.jpg)
[over state][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5srk.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: give `z-index: -1` to  `#box-under`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the `z-index` of  `#box_under` ,`#keys:hover #box_under` , `#box:hover #box_under` to -1000 Like below.

**Note!!** Its not required to reduce the value of `z-index` exactly to -1000 but a negative value smaller than the value of `z-index` of other div.

```
#box-under {
 z-index:-1000;
 }

#keys:hover #box-under {
  right: 0px;
  z-index: -1000;
}

#box:hover #box-under {
  right: 0px;
  z-index: -1000;
}
```

```css
#box {
  width: 180px;
  min-height: 570px;
  background: #4D4D4D;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 9999;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*shadows  */
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 3px #333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 3px #333;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 3px #333;
  -o-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 3px #333;
  /* transparency  */
  opacity: 0.9;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

#box-under {
  width: 600px;
  min-height: 583px;
  background: #4D4D4D;
  position: absolute;
  right: -600px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: -1000;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*shadows  */
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 3px #333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 3px #333;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 3px #333;
  -o-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 3px #333;
  /* transparency  */
  opacity: 0.9;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  /* For IE8 and earlier */
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 1.13) 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 1.13) 0s;
}


/*  xxxxxxxx testing drop down  xxxxxxxx  */

#keys:hover #box-under {
  right: 0px;
  z-index: -1000;
}

#box:hover #box-under {
  right: 0px;
  z-index: -1000;
}

.butz:hover #box-under #box {
  z-index: 999;
  right: 0px;
}


/*  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  */

#logoz {
  min-height: 40px;
  background: #555555;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1.4em;
}

.butz {
  min-height: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #304565;
  padding: 0.9em;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #CCC;
}

.butz:hover {
  background: #218F77;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.butz2 {
  min-height: 20px;
  background: #555555;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #CCC;
  display: flex;
}

.butz2-in:hover {
  background: #41967C;
  color: #FFF;
  border-bottom: #41967C 4px solid;
}

.butz2-in {
  min-height: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #555555;
  padding: 0.9em;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #CCC;
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: #777 4px solid;
}

.butz2-out {
  min-height: 20px;
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #777;
  padding: 0.55em 0.9em;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #CCC;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-bottom: #00B2B2 4px solid;
}

.butz3 {
  min-height: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #dddddd;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1.3em 0.9em;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
}

.butz3:hover {
  background: #CCC;
  color: #2E2E2E;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="logoz">
    <img src="images/page_logo.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <!--  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  -->
  <!--  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  -->
  <div class="butz" id="keys">KEY FEATURES<br />
    <small>The summaries is gone</small>
    <!--  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  -->
    <div id="box-under"></div>
    <!--  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  -->
  </div>
  <!--  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  -->
  <!--  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  -->
  <!--  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  -->
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <div class="butz2">
    <div class="butz2-in">The Company</div>
    <div class="butz2-out"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i></div>
  </div>
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <!--  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  -->
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <div class="butz2">
    <div class="butz2-in">Our Services</div>
    <div class="butz2-out"><i class="fas fa-angle-doub`enter code here`le-left"></i></div>
  </div>
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <div class="butz2">
    <div class="butz2-in">Our Works</div>
    <div class="butz2-out"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i></div>
  </div>
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <div class="butz2">
    <div class="butz2-in">Contact Info</div>
    <div class="butz2-out"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i></div>
  </div>
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <div class="butz3">
    <span class="cube"><i class="fas fa-align-left"></i></span>
    <span class="notes">To maintain and expand our oursd and to...</span>
  </div>
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <div class="butz3">
    <span class="cube"><i class="far fa-bookmark"></i></span> To maintain our commercial presence...
  </div>
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <div class="butz3">
    <span class="cube"><i class="fab fa-odnoklassniki"></i></span> To maintain and expand our commercial to...
  </div>
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <!--  ------- --- + ----------  -->
  <!--  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  -->
</div>
```

Comment: I've posted the answer pls look through it. It will help you to solve the problem. If it is helpful pls accept it.

Comment: if it is helpful for you then, please accept and upvote my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find that TWO problems occur trying to control DHTML javascript outside the problems of a DTD type for the (X)HTML page.

1. You need to place the CSS attribute-name and value *"visibility:visible;"* or *"visibility:hidden;"*  into each CSS style class or "#" layer notation or DIV tag of its style= attribute as appropriate default value.
2. To manipulate the visibility attribute by DHTML it should first be instantiated in the CSS document declaration of classes and layer notations or it may fail the first attempt by the user or outright fail altogether.
   CSS DHTML is generally not able to be manipulated if the attribute has not been declared first, too depending the browser depends the default value to use upon the div!

**Usual default value is "visible" !**